# What is the best way to approach this background image issue?

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image, absolute

**My Goal:**

So I am making a webpage with a map of the USA as the "background image" and on top of that map I have about 10 markers pointing to specific location. The markers are NOT part of the picture thats just me adding them with absolute positioning and top and left with a percentage.

**The Problem:**

As I scale down the page or scroll up and down the markers that I have set with absolute positioning begin to move out of the spot they are suppose to be on because the background-image is getting smaller do to it displaying 100%.

**The Question:**

How can I achieve what I want with the markers on the map where they are suppose to be not moving as the window is being scaled down?

Now I know of only 1 solution and this solution can take a VERY LONG TIME. What I was thinking is instead of positioning the markers that I want on the map with percentage I can do it with pixels and then use a TON of media queries and keep on adjusting it. Not only is this solution going to take extremely long but it also does not seems like the correct way to go about this.

HTML:

```
<div class="container main-content"><!--the map background image is set here-->
<div class="row relative">
    <div class="eq-content-wrap">
        <div class="eq-content">
            <div class="marker"></div> <!--the marker that is positioned absolute-->
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            background: #000;
}
body{ overflow: hidden; }

.main-content{
                background: url('assets/img/map1.jpg') no-repeat top center;
                background-size: contain;
                height: 100% !important;
                width: 100% !important;
}
.eq-content-wrap{
                position: absolute;
                width: 500px !important;
                top: 22%;
                left: 40%;
}

.marker{
                        height: 40px;
                        width: 40px;
                        border-radius: 100%;
                        background-color: red;
                        position: absolute;
                        top: 50%;
                        margin-top: -20px;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `em` instead of `px` to position the markers? `em` scales a lot better than `px` does. Also, instead of absolute positions, try relative positioning, or relative margins. If you can link me to the working page, I can help better.

Comment: Also, you might find HTML image maps useful: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

Comment: @BJSafdie that looks really interesting and may be the solution, I am going to check it out.

Comment: Removing `background-size` from the background image fixes the scale issue. However, the background doesn't stretch across the page, so I'm not sure if that is your desired result.

Comment: @WesFoster let me try it out and see how it looks.

Comment: I take that back. I was referring to content scaling (pressing CTRL+- on keyboard) instead of browser window scaling. Let me look back into it

Comment: @WesFoster seems that when I remove the background-size it does help but then when the view port gets to 1200px and below the background starts to scale down once again. By the way this website it NOT going to be responsive. I set `<meta name="viewport" content="width=1200, initial-scale=0.3">` so that even when it loads on mobile it will look like the desktop version but when you are on the desktop and you shrink the screen it does begin to scale down.

Comment: This is because you have the `background-position` set to `top center`. The `center` is what causes it to move once the browser window width is less than the image width. Change `center` to `left` and it will fix that issue. You'll also need to set the marker's container to be based to the left as well for this to work on wider screens though. Basically, removing all `center` properties would help, but the screen wouldn't be centered on a wide screen. I'm posting an answer to prevent having so many comments

Comment: @WesFoster I see whats going on here. Changing the position to top left is better but the real problem here is the market with that video. that specific container move when the screen expands. I re-uploaded the new styles, look at the page again and scale larger and small and you will see what I mean about the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your background image's size is set to 100%: `background-size: 100%`. This means that when the browser tries to scale the content, the background does not scale with it (it stays 100%).

Your best bet is to remove the `background-size` property completely. This allows the markers to stay in place when the page scales, however, you won't get the full-screen background effect that you currently have (unless you have a larger image).

The background will still move, however, once the browser window width is less than the image's width. This is because you have the background-position set to top center. The center is what causes it to move once the browser window width is less than the image width. Change center to left and it will fix that issue. You'll also need to set the marker's container to be based to the left as well for this to work on wider screens though. Basically, removing all center properties would help, but the screen wouldn't be centered on a wide screen.

Comment: After many hours of attempts I came up with a proper solution Using your method and some of mine. I positioned the elements with the background image 50% from the left with no background-size. Then here is the trick, lets say I had a 1000px wide image that I scaled centered with absolute and the negative margin to even it out, if you scale under 1000px the image starts to get cut off so I added a media query the size of the image and said left: 0 instead of 50% and it all works out very nice. Thanks a ton  for the help Wes really appreciate it man.

Comment: The media query is a great addition, Lucas! I'm glad my long response and cold supper wasn't in vain :)

Answer (score 0):

Try substituting `css` `:before` pseudo element for `.marker` ; set percentage unit values utilizing `calc()`

```css
    html,
    body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      background: #000;
    }
    body {
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .main-content {
      background: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/300) no-repeat top center;
      background-size: contain;
      height: 100% !important;
      width: 100% !important;
    }
    .eq-content-wrap {
      position: absolute;
      width: 500px !important;
      top: 22%;
      left: 40%;
    }
    .main-content:before {
      content: " ";
      height: calc(12.5%);
      width: calc(5%);
      border-radius: 100%;
      background-color: red;
      position: absolute;
      top: calc(50%);
      left: calc(50%);
      margin-top: calc(1%);
    }
```

```html
<div class="container main-content">
  <!--the map background image is set here-->
  <div class="row relative">
    <div class="eq-content-wrap">
      <div class="eq-content">
        <div class="marker"></div>
        <!--the marker that is positioned absolute-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/o79rpawc/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this method still has the marker moving though